# HashSet<T> on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there no System.Collections.Generic.HashSet on Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Yeah, I discovered this recently as well, and it made me sad.  What are you going to do with it?  There may be another option.

Comment: I have an unordered list of items (an item has a key-field), and a set of user-favourites, where only the keys of some items are stored. When the user's favourites should be displayed, I'm iterating over the list of all items and for each item I check, whether it's key is in the favourites-set.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 .NET libraries are comparable to what is provided in Silverlight 3.0 (which doesn't have `HashSet`).  You can build something like a `HashSet` using a `Dictionary`.  For example, see this MSDN forum post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/e1dd3571-dfb8-4abe-b63a-62106d6a4965/

Answer (score 3):

It is supported in SL4

[HashSet(Of T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28VS.96%29.aspx)

However on Widows Phone 7, is compatible with Silverlight 3.0 API and SL 4 is not supported. So the answer is no, you can not use HashSet for Windows Phone 7 yet.

Answer (score 3):

It is not supported on Windows Phone.  Windows Phone version of Silverlight contains some parts of regular Silverlight but not all.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/17CD2505-6C77-4644-9CB6-FFA2CE285942)