# Observable Hashset for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am currently working on a windows phone project which required to use an Observable Hashset.
I have found that there is some code on github that implement this by inherit INotifyCollectionChanged and Hashset. But there is no hashset for windows phone. So I have found that there is someone guide for alternate implemention of hashset for windows phone using dictionary(Only Sample code not the full code). But I didn't find any of alternate Observable Hashset implement for windows phone.

So I want some guide on implement of Observable Hashset for Windows Phone or just full code implement of hashset for Winddows Phone.

Originally, I just want an Obserevable collection with no duplicate member. just guide me.

Comment: This question maybe similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770785/hashsett-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: @RomanGolenok I mean Observeable Hashset, Not just a guide to implement hashset by dictionary.